# My R function accepts individual column names but not lists of column names when passed through map()

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

After many months of using this forum, I finally
have a question for the community that I can't seem to
find sufficiently addressed elsewhere.

In R, I created a function that accepts individual
column names but not lists of column names when passed through
map(). The problem appears to be one of evaluation, so have
tried quo() and enquo(), but since I don't properly
understand how they work, I need some help.

I've tried iterating through different versions of the function
(commenting out the offending lines as per error messages) but
this only moves the problem around without solving it. Thanks
in advance.

```
# Load:
library(tidyverse)

# Create df:
set.seed(12)
df <- tibble(col1 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE),
             col2 = sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE),
             col3 = sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE))

# My function:
my_function <- function(col_name) {
  
  df <- df %>%
    filter({{ col_name }} != 1) %>%
    group_by(fct_relevel(factor(col1), "c", "b", "a")) %>%
    mutate(col4 = 5 - {{ col_name }}) %>%
    summarise("Score" = mean(col4)) %>%
    rename("Levels" =
             `fct_relevel(factor(col1), "c", "b", "a")`)
  
  return(df)
  
}

# List of col_names to pass to function:
col_list <- list(df$col2, df$col3)

# Attempt function in map() using list of col_names:
map(col_list, my_function)

# Gives error message:
# Error in `mutate()`:
# ! Problem while computing `col4 = 5 - c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
#                                        4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L)`.
# ✖ `col4` must be size 2 or 1, not 10.
# ℹ The error occurred in group 1: fct_relevel(factor(col1), "c",
#                                             "b", "a") = c.
```

Comment: The `filter` and `mutate` look like they can only handle one column.  What were you hoping would be the result of passing two columns?

Comment: @MichaelDewar `map` would return a `list`, essentially the result of `list(my_function(col2), my_function(col3))`, it wouldn't try to call `my_function(col2, col3)`. I assume that is what OP is trying to get. (Though please correct me if I'm wrong and clarify the desired output in any case, dalexco!)

Comment: Apologies, @Michael and @Gregor: my actual dataframe has 10 columns I want to input into my function. The function creates a table of means by level of col1 (i.e., the mean of the target variable by a, b, and c). I can run `my_function(col2)` all the way up to `my_function(col11)` (10 lines of code) and get my desired 10 tables. But I was hoping to be able to do this in a single line, by passing the 10 column names as a list through map(): `map(my_list, my_function)`. I've used map() several times and never had this issue so wondered what it was about my function that I'd done wrong.

Comment: How is what you're looking for different then `df %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarize(across(everything(), ~mean(5-.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`?  I'm not sure I see the need for `map` and a special function.

Comment: @MichaelDewar, thank you! It isn't, and neither do I (anymore). I was overcomplicating things. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One issue you're having is that `col_list` is not actually a list of column names, but rather the actual data from those columns.

I'm not totally sure what output you're hoping for, but I'm guessing it's the `full_join` of the result of `my_function` applied to each column.  One way to do that is:

```
new_f <- function(...){
    df %>% 
        mutate(across(-col1, ~if_else(.x == 1L, NA, .x))) %>% 
        group_by("Levels" = fct_relevel(factor(col1), "c", "b", "a")) %>% 
        select(Levels, ...) %>% 
        summarize(across(everything(), ~ mean(5- .x, na.rm = TRUE)))
}

new_f(col2, col3)
new_f(col2)
new_f(col3)
```

Now, I realize that maybe I have missed your true intention.  For example, maybe you're trying to understand how to use `purrr::map`.  If so, please comment or update your question.

In any case, you should check out [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)